# After add an image to product gallery, how to select that image as product image?

Tags: magento-1.7, image

I add an image to product's image gallery with this code:

```
// $filePath: image full path
$mediaArray = array(
    "thumbnail"   => $filePath,
    "small_image" => $filePath,
    "image"       => $filePath,
);

$product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, $mediaArray, true, false);

$product->save();
```

After this code, the image will be added to gallery but it is unselected. How can I select this image as "base image" (and/or Small Image, Thumbnail)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$mediaArray` parameter must be an array with values any of the image types you want to set.
So instead of :

```
$mediaArray = array(
    "thumbnail"   => $filePath,
    "small_image" => $filePath,
    "image"       => $filePath,
);
```

Use this:

```
$mediaArray = array(
    "thumbnail",
    "small_image",
    "image",
);
```

Or any other combination of image attributes you have even an empty array if you don't want to set the image as main image for an attribute.